# schema.org microdata - image required for Article

Tags: html, semantic-markup, microdata, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

Every example I find for https://schema.org/Article gives at least one error in the Google Structured Data Testing Tool

Supposedly `headline` is now required; that's fine, just change `itemprop="name"` to `itemprop="name headline"`

But it also gives the error:

```
A value for the image field is required.
Required by:
Articles Rich Snippets
```

- why is an image required for Articles?
- why isn't this documented anywhere?
- what should I give as an image?

I've heard people say the image should be an image ***of*** the article (literally interpreting the documentation: "An image of the item.") - Like an actual screenshot of the article. Isn't that useless? Is that even correct? Do I have to give an image? Will the same blank image or logo be ok for every article? Or would duplicate images get penalised due to not being relevant?

Comment: Okay schema.org aren't requiring it but there's some info from Google here https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Schema.org (the vocabulary) doesn’t require any properties.

Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool is not a Schema.org validator. The tool primarily tests if your use of Schema.org conforms to Google’s own requirements for showing one of their Rich Snippets (or similar features/products).

So if Google’s tool says that a "value for the image field is required", this does not mean that you are technically required to provide it, or that something bad (like a ranking penalty) happens if you don’t provide it. It just means that Google won’t display a Rich Snippet for this document on their SERPs.

Google typically documents the properties *they* require for their features on https://developers.google.com/structured-data/ (example: their [Article Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles)).

Discussing which images are okay in Google’s eyes is off-topic on Stack Overflow (you might get help on [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)).

From Schema.org’s perspective: the [`image` property](http://schema.org/image) is, as you note, defined to have an "image of the item" as value. For `Product`, it could be a photograph of the product, for `Person` a portrait etc. For an `Article`, the equivalent would be a photo/screenshot of the article itself; however, that’s often not really useful. So I think it’s common practice to specify an image that *represents* this article somehow: practically speaking, an image that could be shown as teaser image for your article. But you should not use the `image` property just because an image is part of the article (so don’t use it for all images, and don’t use it if you have no image that would/should represent the article); for such cases, you could use the [`hasPart` property](http://schema.org/hasPart) instead.